# Вращение не относительно центра css

Tags: css, анимация

Сделал анимацию вращения на 360 градусов, но круг дергается, а не статичен.
Посмотреть можно здесь. https://jsfiddle.net/a7e3mwph/

transform-origin: center не помог.

```
@keyframes wheel {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg)
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg)
    }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a7e3mwph/

Comment: Но в Вашем примере если включить анимацию - круг статичен и крутится относительно центра.

Comment: я уменьшил круг, чтобы было лучше видно https://jsfiddle.net/a7e3mwph/

Comment: Выложите сюда это прямо в Ваш вопрос, для этого есть конпка "Фрагмент кода", которая воспроизводит Ваш HTML/CSS/JS код.

Comment: Вращать круг... Ещё и два элемента использовать... и position absolute. Я, кажется, чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: колесо тоже круг. решил встроенной svg анимацией

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Используйте встроенную в svg анимацию.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]